# Ruby. Algorithm insertion sort

Tags: ruby, algorithm, sorting, variables

Sorry maybe a simple question but I can not figure it out. I have a program that sorts an array:

```
def  insertionsort(num)
  for j in 1..(num.length - 1)
      key = num[j]
      i = j - 1
      while i >= 0 and num[i] > key
          num[i+1] = num[i]
          i = i - 1
      end
      num[i+1] = key
  end
end

ar = Array.new(10) { rand(1...11) }

insertionsort(ar)
insertionsort(ar)
insertionsort(ar)
insertionsort(ar)
insertionsort(ar)

p ar
```

But after the first sort insertionsort(ar) i must to use the same array, but after the first sort variable ar take sorted array

Comment: can you please explain your expected result better? I fail to understand your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just clone your array to keep you first array as before:

```
def  insertionsort(num)
  res = num.dup
  for j in 1..(res.length - 1)
    key = res[j]
    i = j - 1
    while i >= 0 and res[i] > key
      res[i+1] = res[i]
      i = i - 1
    end
    res[i+1] = key
 end
 res
end

ar = Array.new(10) { rand(1...11) }
res = insertionsort(ar)
p ar
p res
```